# GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h not found after reopening project

Tags: ios, google-maps

I imported using this: `<GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`, and it didn't work. Using `"GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"` didn't work either. There is only 1 way which I can get it to work, which is to reimport everything when I open the project in Xcode. Somehow when I close and reopen the project the link to Google Maps is gone.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How to make xcode find GoogleMaps.h? @rebello95